# Cannot return data from NSURLConnection. Why and how do I accomplish this?

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, nsurlconnection, block

Disclaimer... I've only been working with Objective C for a week now and working on my first app that is very heavy on making requests to a server.

I've tried a variety of solutions to try and get this to return from within the NSURLConnection block... but nothing seems to work.

Can someone explain WHY this does not work, and how to enable myself to return data created in this block?

Thank you!

```
__block NSDictionary *dictionaryData;
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
    completionHandler: ^(NSURLResponse * response, NSData * data, NSError * error)
    {
        NSHTTPURLResponse * httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
        if(httpResponse.statusCode == 200)
        {
            dictionaryData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        }
    }];
return dictionaryData;
```

Comment: If you are able to target iOS 7 and newer, look at `NSURLSession` instead, it is the successor to `NSURLConnection`. Here's a really good article on it: [objc.io: From NSURLConnection to NSURLSession](http://www.objc.io/issue-5/from-nsurlconnection-to-nsurlsession.html)

Comment: sendAsynchronousRequest is *asynchronous*.  It is going to return immediately, so your dictionaryData will remain unset.  Put a breakpoint inside your completion handler and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: I'm working in xCode 4.6. Otherwise I'd be learning Swift and all that fun stuff.